# Transform longitude, latitude values (qualitatively) to a 100 x 100 2D-Plane

Tags: python, coordinate-system

I'm trying to transform a lot of long|latitude values to a system where I can display the points in my program that is not capable of GIS transformations/visualisations.

The points should be more or less correctly positioned in a grid of variable size for example 0 -> 100 in x and 0 -> 100 in the y-direction.

I tried a simple equirectangular projection with

```
x = R * long * cos(7.468429)
y = R * lat
```

but the values are still way too big to be usable even after dividing by 1000 f.e. :

```
17.898752575196323, 328.1974554483615
17.89925257519632, 328.1979554483615
```

I'm using Python for calculations with pyproj for transformations.

Comment: Wouldn't a 200x100 (or 100x50) grid be more appropriate, to avoid compressing the X dimension?

Comment: "7.468429" radians is a magic number -- what does it represent?

Comment: Is the issue that you're trying to use some (non-conical) projection and you want the values to be already transformed into x, y coordinates rather than lat, lon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use geopandas. You can create a GeoDataFrame from an array of lat/lon points and set the CRS to whatever you'd like (here I use WGS84: 'epsg:4326'):

```py
In [1]: import geopandas as gpd
In [2]: import numpy as np

In [3]: lons = np.arange(-175, 180, 10)
In [4]: lats = np.arange(-85, 90, 10)
In [5]: xx, yy = map(np.ravel, np.meshgrid(lons, lats))

In [5]: df = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
   ...:     {},
   ...:     geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(xx, yy, crs='epsg:4326'),
   ...: )
   ...:
```

you can see this has defined points on a lat/lon grid:

```py
In [6]: # using transparency to show point density
   ...: df.plot(alpha=0.3, linewidth=0)
```

[image: regular grid on a Plate Carree or Conical projection]

You can use [`df.to_crs()`](https://geopandas.org/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.to_crs.html) to reproject the geometries in [any PROJ projection](https://proj.org/operations/projections/index.html). I'll illustrate with some really wacky projections below to show how this works, but you could choose any projection from the PROJ library you'd like.

For example, [Interrupted Goode Homolosine](https://proj.org/operations/projections/igh.html)
:

```py
In [7]: df.to_crs('+proj=igh').plot(alpha=0.3, linewidth=0)
```

[image: regular grid on an Interrupted Geode Homolosine projection]

Alternatively, [Lambert Azimuthal Equal Area](https://proj.org/operations/projections/laea.html):

```py
In [8]: df.to_crs('+proj=laea').plot(alpha=0.3, linewidth=0)
```

[image: regular grid on a Lambert Azimuthal Equal Area projection]

You can turn any of these back into a pandas dataframe (e.g. for writing to csv) with df.geometry.x and df.geometry.y:

```py
In [ 9]: transformed = df.to_crs('+proj=laea')
In [10]: out_df = pd.DataFrame({
    ...:     'lon': transformed.geometry.x,
    ...:     'lat': transformed.geometry.y})
    ...:
```

And if you're hoping to normalize this to a [0, 1] range or something you can then manipulate the values:

```py
In [11]: normalized = (
    ...:     (out_df - out_df.min()) / (out_df.max() - out_df.min())
    ...:

In [12]: normalized.plot.scatter(x='lon', y='lat', alpha=0.3, linewidth=0)
```

[image: regular grid on a Lambert Azimuthal Equal Area projection normalized to being between 0 and 1]

See the [GeoPandas docs on Managing Projections](https://geopandas.org/docs/user_guide/projections.html) for more info

Comment: Specifically, the normalisation solved my issues! 
Thanks a lot!